# Flex DateChooser component, 42 days, show days of prev/next month

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

On the DateChooser component, it shows the days for only the current month... but i'd like to show some of the previous month's days and some of the next month's days.

Is there a property to set on the DateChooser component to show 42 days. I mean, to show some of the previous month's days + the current month's days + some of the next month's days.  I'm not sure what this is called...

If you look at a typical month calendar, for example for June 2011 it shows:

```
S  M  T  W  Th F  Sa
20 30 31 1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 1  2 
3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

However, on the DateChooser control its like this:

```
S  M  T  W  Th F  Sa
         1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
```

Is there a property that I've overlooked which shows some of the days from the prev. month and next month in the current month view?  Or would I need to extend the DateChooser component and override a method?  Would appreciate some pointers on that.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I call it leading and trailing days; and I do not believe DateChooser supports this by default.  So, you'll have to extend the DateChooser, and most likely the (undocumented) CalendarLayout class, which performs the DateChooser layouts. It'll probably be a bit tedious, but definitely doable.

The [Flextras Calendar](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=15) does support leading and trailing days; however it is designed for displaying dated data; not for selecting dates.  Since your use case appears to be selecting dates; you'll probably be better off modding the Flex DateChooser instead of trying to shoehorn our component into your use case.

Comment: Thanks Flextras.. I'll try to modify the CalendarLayout class and will report back of my findings/success...

Comment: @justLearn will you get result of your effort? i am here in same problem..?